# Dynamic appending of values in select dropdown appends empty field in dropdown when the option contains spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple dropdown select which value is appended by input from a text box.

The appending process is fine when the text in input is a single word without spaces, but appends an empty field when the text contains space.

> example:  "New York" will be appended empty.

```
// City is a text box from which new city name is to be taken 
var newCity = $('#City').val();

//selectCity is a dropdown of the list of city
$('.selectCity').append('<option value='+newCity+'>'+newCity+'</option>');
```

Thank you before hands

Comment: $('.selectCity').append('<option value="'+newCity+'">'+newCity+'</option>'); // this field is converted into "$('.selectCity').append(''+newCity+'');" by stack overflow I dont know why

Comment: turns out I value='+newCity+' this was the problem with two word option. it should have been value="'+newCity+'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i have made a fiddle and added an option with spaces dynamically to the existing select box and it's working:

```
<select id = "select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Plain Script:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
var newOptionText = "Text with spaces"; //your input box value will come here.
option.text = newOptionText;
option.value = "newOption";
var select = document.getElementById("select");
select.appendChild(option);
```

Now the select box will also have another option "Text With Spaces".

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/t5ay9mcs/)**

Comment: this is also appening an empty field

Comment: see my updated answer and demo.. it works now. don't forget to accept this answer if it worked.

Comment: thanks mate. I don't know why this worked and my method didn't. Can you explain??

Comment: i think you have misplaced the quotes, " should be outside and ' should be the one covering the value

Answer (score 0):

**You can not append text directly to Select Box.**

Select box contains a set of `option` and if you want to add new `option` then firstly you need to create an `option` & the append it to your `Select Box`.

Try this-

```
 $('.selectCity').append('<option value="'+newCity+'">'+newCity+'</option>');//creating new option then append it to select
```

Comment: I have used this same code. I am trying to post the question in this format but the field has been modified to $('.selectCity').append(''+newCity+'');

Comment: I am new to this stackover flow. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectCity').append("<option value='new york'>new york</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way to add items typed into a text box into a select list

Javascript:

```
$("input[type=button]").on("click",function(){
    $("select").append($("<option>" + $("input[type=text]").val() + "</option>"));
});
```

HTML:

```
<select></select><br/> 
New Item: <input type=text><input type=button value="add">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needs some Speech Marks

```
$('.selectCity').append('<option value="'+newCity+'">'+newCity+'</option>');
```